# Application crashes at startup (Lollipop 5.1.1, Tablet)

Tags: android, tablet, android-5.1.1-lollipop

My application is showing very strange behavior for a tablet device, it crashes as it launches (Lollipop - 5.1.1 Tablet device, without any meaningful logs) though it runs fine on mobile devices even including Lollipop - 5.0 phone device with almost same log report

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Log report

```
E/com.samsung.app: [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> UIMK:1376 [0:0] time : 17:31
E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2614 [07-31 17:31:00.264]
? E/AffinityControl: AffinityControl: registerfunction enter
? E/AffinityControl: AffinityControl: registerfunction enter
E/WindowState: getStack: Window{2bd3ac2f u0 d0 com.project.debug/com.screens.account_login.AccountLoginActivity} couldn't find taskId=500 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1059 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1778 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2363 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1505
E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote: v2
E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
com.switchsolutions.agricultureapplication.mobilink.debug E/StudioProfiler: Studio Profilers encountered an unexpected error. Consider reporting a bug, including logcat output below.
    See also: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html#studio-bugs
Failed to capture application
E/WindowState: getStack: Window{2bd3ac2f u0 d0 com.project.debug/com.screens.account_login.AccountLoginActivity} couldn't find taskId=500 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1059 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1778 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2363 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1505
E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
```

Comment: well, it does say that `Studio Profilers encountered an unexpected error. Consider reporting a bug, including logcat output below`, might just be an issue with android studio ?

Comment: try disabling Studio Profiler and see if it works.

Comment: @a_local_nobody, yes it is happening on the actual device as mentioned, it's a tablet 5.1.1

Comment: @ZohaibAmir, I don't think it would be the case as signed apk also crashes on tablet 5.1.1